# System.Threading api for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to use the system.threading.thread api for windows phone 8 development but visual studio is giving me error. My platform is windows 8.1 , visual studio 2013 and sdk 8.1 for windows phone development. I have googled some links and found that thread is available for windows phone 8 development. Can any one suggest anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx 
This link gives all about the System.Threading.Thread class. It says that :
It has been supported in Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Silverlight 8.1.
There you also can find a working sample for this class.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: I tried my best to import system.threading.thread, but it doesnt work. Only system.threading.tasks are available.

Comment: System.Threading.Thread type is not part of Metro surface. Did you check the right reference assembly?

Comment: What do u suggest then? any Alternative, because i want to update my interface and update UI Objects in thread.

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke will help you update your UI on main thread.